# My second and third intents are not working; when I type 13 or higher, it goes to intent1

Tags: android, android-studio

[It should be that when I type 13-17, it goes to intent2 and when I type 18 or higher, it goes to intent3, but this is not the case.

public class nextscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public Button btn;
public EditText enterage;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nextscreen);

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(nextscreen.this, R.raw.background_music);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.start();

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.agebutton);
    enterage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterage);
    
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int inputage = enterage.getInputType();

            if (inputage <= 12) {
                Intent int1 = new Intent(nextscreen.this, nextscreen1.class);
                startActivity(int1);
            }


            else if (inputage <= 17){
                Intent int2 = new Intent(nextscreen.this, nextscreen2.class);
                startActivity(int2);
            }


            else {
                Intent int3 = new Intent(nextscreen.this, nextscreen3.class);
                startActivity(int3);
            }
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lh2hn.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`getInputType()` is not a value from EditText, it's a type of EditText, e.g. `textPersonName, textPersonName`, etc.

if you want value, you need to use `getText()`

```
String value= enterage.getText().toString();
int intValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
```